# python selenium with chrome - web page detects selenium and doesn't allow login

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to login into the following page using python, selenium and chrome:

https://www.etoro.com/login

You don't need my username and password to recreate this scenario. Use a made up username and password, it will work the same. If I open a 'normal' chrome window (so not using selenium) and try to login with any username/password (assuming it si incorrect) u get an 'invalid username/password' error.

[image: normal chrome login]

If I try to login using python selenium and chrome and use my username/password i get an error saying 'An error has occured, please try again'.

[image: chrome login using selenium]

Web page therefore recognises selenium and doesn't let me in. Is there anything I can do? I want this 'invalid username/password' also when using selenium and chrome, so that I can login with my correct username and password

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot login using the normal chromedriver, but luckily you have two options:

## Undetected chromedriver

Install it with `pip install undetected-chromedriver` ([documentation](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)), and then run

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
# do stuff to log in
```

## Custom user profile

Alternatively, you can use the normal chromedriver and load a user profile where you are already logged in. With this method when you run `driver.get(url)` you will be already logged in, because it uses the cookies of the user profile. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134802/8157304) you can find a tutorial on how to create a user profile and load it in chromedriver

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(..., options=options)
driver.get(url)
# now you are already logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with a different site where I couldn't login with selenium. I found out that you can start Google Chrome in the Command Prompt with a specified port that you can then "connect to" (sorry I'm no expert in this so my terminology might be wrong) and it had fixed my issue.

The code I'm using is:

```
from os import getcwd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from subprocess import Popen
from winreg import OpenKey, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, EnumValue


#Service Manager automatically updates chromedriver
service = Service()

#Gets path of 'chrome.exe' on your computer
chrome_folder_path = EnumValue(OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe"), 0)[1]

url = "your url"

#Important argument here is the port '9229'
args = f'--remote-debugging-port=9229 --user-data-dir="{getcwd()}/chromeprofile" --disable-gpu --start-maximized --log-level=3 --disable-extensions' #--headless

#Launches Google chrome with the desired url and args
Popen(f'{chrome_folder_path} {url} {args}')
sleep(2)

#I'm sorry for not being able to explain this but essentially it connects to the port 9229 and making you able to control the browser with selenium
sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
sc.setSystemProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", rf"chromedriver.exe");
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9229")

global driver
driver = Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

I understand that my code is very far from ideal but I hope it at least helps you in some way.