# How to avoid login page and access the website using session/selenium access existing browser history using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

google reacptcha issue faced when accessed the website using selenium python in automation.using session to avoid the login page  with web driver ,is there any chance in selenium python?

Comment: Post the code you've tried and the URL, then explain your issue clearly.

Comment: any sample code?

Comment: yes, this should be possible using cookies. Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to load a user profile where you are already logged in. With this method when you run `driver.get(url)` you will be already logged in, because it uses the cookies of the user profile. This is the code in python

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(..., options=options)
driver.get(url)
# now you are already logged in
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134802/8157304) you find a step by step tutorial on how to create a user profile in Chrome and load it in chromedriver.