# I'm writing a code where I can enter Instagram and get the follower list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, bots

Hello ı'm a beginner coder

I want to login to instagram using selenium and get my follower list but my code But the code I wrote does not give any error or output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class İnstagram:
    
    def __init__(self,name,password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        
    def signIn(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")
        time.sleep(1)
        
        name = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/input").send_keys(self.username)
        psw = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[2]/div/label/input").send_keys(self.password)
        self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[3]").click()
        time.sleep(7)
        
    
    def getFollowers(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/emirhaninmalikanesi/followers/")
        
        followers = self.browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"._ab8w._ab94._ab99._ab9h._ab9m._ab9o._abcm")        
        for user in followers:
            name = user.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".x1i10hfl.xjbqb8w.x6umtig.x1b1mbwd.xaqea5y.xav7gou.x9f619.x1ypdohk.xt0psk2.xe8uvvx.xdj266r.x11i5rnm.xat24cr.x1mh8g0r.xexx8yu.x4uap5.x18d9i69.xkhd6sd.x16tdsg8.x1hl2dhg.xggy1nq.x1a2a7pz.notranslate._a6hd").get_attribute("href")
            print(name)
            

        
        
instagram = İnstagram(username,password)
instagram.signIn()
instagram.getFollowers()
```

Comment: are username and password defined? 3rd to bottom line when you're creating an instance of the instagram class

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: yes i am getting instagram data from file named instaUser. I forgot to add it here. In the first command line it says instaUser import username, password

Comment: When I run the code I get neither an error message nor any output

Comment: this code throws an error on this line `instagram = İnstagram(username,password)` because `username` and `password` are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two flaws

1. Before login you have to close the cookies dialog, otherwise the code raises `ElementClickInterceptedException` when trying to click on "Log in".
2. No use of selenium built-in timeout methods (`driver.implicitly_wait` or `WebDriverWait`) to wait for an element to be found. This causes `followers` to be an empty list.

Corrected code

```
driver.implicitly_wait(9) # driver waits up to 9 seconds for an element to be found

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='dialog']/div/button[contains(.,'cookie')]").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/input").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[2]/div/label/input").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[3]").click()

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/emirhaninmalikanesi/followers/")
followers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"._ab8w._ab94._ab99._ab9h._ab9m._ab9o._abcm")
for user in followers:
    name = user.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".x1i10hfl.xjbqb8w.x6umtig.x1b1mbwd.xaqea5y.xav7gou.x9f619.x1ypdohk.xt0psk2.xe8uvvx.xdj266r.x11i5rnm.xat24cr.x1mh8g0r.xexx8yu.x4uap5.x18d9i69.xkhd6sd.x16tdsg8.x1hl2dhg.xggy1nq.x1a2a7pz.notranslate._a6hd").get_attribute("href")
    print(name)
```

As a final consideration, notice that you can avoid the login process by loading in selenium a user profile where you are already logged in. For more info look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75434260/8157304