# Avoid login each time i run script in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a website using selenium pyhton. When I go to my website using driver.get(), it goes to microsoft login screen and after login it require two factor authentication and after that it opens the actual website.
Now the problem is when i add new script in my code and i want to check if it is working right, I have to run all the above steps for login and then run the new code.

It is really time consuming. I need suggestions for avoid login each time just to check if my next lines of code are working or not.
I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Cookies

To avoid the login process you have two options, the first one involves saving cookies in a file and loading it when necessary.

```
url = 'https://www.microsoft.com'
driver.get(url)
# manually enter username and password
import pickle
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
driver.quit()
```

then restart the webdriver and run

```
driver.get(url)
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
```

### User profile

Alternatively, you can load a user profile where you are already logged in. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134802/8157304) you find a step by step tutorial on how to create a user profile in Chrome.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(..., options=options)
driver.get(url)
```