# Claim a GitHub issue using Selenium or any other web scraping library

Tags: github, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to build a small project on Web Scraping.

During Hacktoberfest or say GSOC when contributors need to solve more number of issues they prefer easy issues like the ones with label **Good First Issue**, but as during those events there are large number of contributors, one who comments on it first claims the issue. So, for claiming a **Good First Issue** one needs to constantly look for new issue and comment on it to claim it, which is really tiresome.

So, I came up with an idea to use web scraping libraries like Selenium to keep watch on any new **Good First Issue** and comment "Claim" on it.

I know how to look out for new issue with **Good First Issue** label on it. But I don't know how to tackle the main part of commenting on that issue.

Please help me come up with a solution of Watching out on a new **Good First Issue** and commenting on it to claim it. Is it possible to do it or I should leave the idea?

Edited code with commenting included but getting some errors.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website='https://github.com/ToolJet/ToolJet/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc'
path='C:\\Users\vedant\OneDrive\Desktop'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get(website)

issue_labels = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "IssueLabel")

for issue_label in issue_labels:
    if issue_label.text == 'up-for-grabs':
        issue_parent_element = issue_label.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
        issue_grandparent_element = issue_parent_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
        issue_link_element = issue_grandparent_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Link--primary")
        issue_link = issue_link_element.get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(issue_link)
        comment_box = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "textarea")
        comment_box.send_keys("Claiming this issue")
        submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Comment')]")
        submit_button.click()
        break

driver.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vedant\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    comment_box = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "textarea")
  File "C:\Users\vedant\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\vedant\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\vedant\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"textarea"}
```

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service, but also this doesn't seem like a thing you should be writing as it only makes the problem worse.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try to write code to do the following: (1) once you get the `href`, run `driver.get(href)` to load the issue page (2) using `driver.find_element` locate the form to enter the comment and click on it (3) write input with `send_keys` (4) press enter. Try this, then put here your code and ask if you have any problem

Comment: @soundwave Sure I will try it and post the updated code

Comment: `issue_link = issue_label.get_attribute('href')` is wrong, what you get is the label link not the issue link

Comment: @soundwave I am able to successfully retrieve the link of issue with a particular tag(here for convenience I have used "up-for-grabs"). Driver is opening the issue page but after that it's not working. It says not able to find element with tagname textarea. I also tried to select the comment box textarea using XPath but it isn't working.

Please suggest me any other way to to select the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` may be due to the fact that the comment box is not fully loaded yet when you try to find it using `find_element`. To avoid this we can use `WebDriverWait(driver, n)` which try to find the element for `n` seconds.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://github.com/ToolJet/ToolJet/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc'
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 9)

issue_xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'up-for-grabs')]/parent::span/preceding-sibling::a"
issue = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, issue_xpath)))
print('Selected issue:', issue.text)
driver.get(issue.get_attribute('href'))

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
comment_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "new_comment_field")))
comment_box.send_keys("Claiming this issue", Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only hurdle is how should I keep GitHub signed in in webdriver. It needs to be signed in to comment.

Comment: @VedantBorkar You can use cookies or an user profile, look here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75589648/8157304