# What could be causing an error in Selenium after adding User-data-Dir?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I basically want to set my default profile in the Selenium WebDriver. The same code was working before I reset my window, but after resetting, it gives an error. Here is the code.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_userdata_dir = 'C:\\Users\\abdul\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default'
option = Options()
option.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={chrome_userdata_dir}")
option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
```

If I run it now, it does not open Chrome with the default profile. It opens it casually, like without a default profile.
If I change the path of chrome_user_dir to the following, it gives an error but open chrome with default profile.

```
chrome_userdata_dir = 'C:\\Users\\abdul\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'
```

The error logs are following

```
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\main.py", line 135, in <module>
    automate_yt_pals(_headless)
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\subpal_subscribers\automate_yt_pals.py", line 56, in automate_yt_pals
    driver = Chrome(service=Service(path), options=option)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\LinuxData\Documents\TwitchVideoAutomator\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x005B37D3]
        (No symbol) [0x00548B81]
        (No symbol) [0x0044B36D]
        (No symbol) [0x0046B7EF]
        (No symbol) [0x00466FC9]
        (No symbol) [0x004A1ED5]
        (No symbol) [0x004A1B2C]
        (No symbol) [0x0049B216]
        (No symbol) [0x00470D97]
        (No symbol) [0x0047253D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0082ABF2+2510930]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00858EC1+2700065]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0085C86C+2714828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00663480+645344]
        (No symbol) [0x00550FD2]
        (No symbol) [0x00556C68]
        (No symbol) [0x00556D4B]
        (No symbol) [0x00560D6B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76B27D69+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77AFB74B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x77AFB6CF+191]
```

Well, one more thing to mention is that I upgraded my Python version from 3.9 to 3.11, the latest version. I hope all this information will help trace down the error.

Using:

```
Python3.11, selenium==4.8.2, webdriver-manager==3.8.5
```

More Info the **chrome://version** shows profile path as follow:

```
Profile Path:   C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

***Edit:
It look like the versions of chrome driver and chrome not matching***
***Only available driver on [chrome driver site](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) is:***

[image]

***My chrome version***

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the profile directory (i.e. `Default`) from the `chrome_userdata_dir`. Moreover, you cannot use the Default profile, but you have to create a new one ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134802/8157304) you find a step by step tutorial on how to create a user profile in Chrome). Then run this

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\gtu\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 3")
```

Comment: Well I tried making new profile and adding it here and same error nothing change.

Comment: @RULERKING Did you replace `Profile 3` with your profile folder?

Comment: Yes I already tried all the simple methods available on stackoverflow

Comment: @RULERKING Did you using cookies instead of a user profile?

Comment: Nope i did not try that.

Comment: @RULERKING Check here where I explain how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/75589648/8157304

Comment: It was resolved using cookies.